# orientdb: How to keep the vertices fixed？

Tags: orientdb

I have a question about the graph editor. How can I keep the vertices fixed when I select some vertices? Now if I select some new vertices, the old vertices will move automatically.

Comment: PLEASE ADD WHAT YOU HAVE TRIED SO FAR ??

Comment: For example, I run a query ‘select * from Car’, and  the vertices will be  shown in the canvas. And then, I run 'select * from Company', the car vertices will move automatically in the canvas when the Company vertices are shown. I hope the car vertices keep still. What code/command do I need?

Answer (score 1):

If you want see the vertices from Car and Company and both classes extends V you can run this command:

```
select from V
```

this is the output:

[image]

Instead if you have some edges between this two classes you can still use the command above or, if you want to see which Company made a Car, you can use this command:

```
select name,out('made_by').name as Company from Car unwind Company
```

this is the output:

[image]

Hope it helps

Regards

Answer (score 0):

For all I know, you can't keep fixed the old vertices.